# Surface Power Density of Fluorescing Reaction

Tags: pcr, light

I am looking to find out what is the ballpark power density of a fluorescing PCR reaction using a SYBR Green or Taq Man dye might be. Is it on the order of $E_e=1mW/cm^2$, less or more? Any help of data would be useful.

Comment: shouldn't amount of light you detect depend on the excitation power? and total volume, and geometry of reaction volume?...

Comment: @aandreev Yes it would, I'm sure things like the amounts of reactants would also play into this. With that said, is there any ballpark for any currently used devices on the market?